# Import two modules with same name at top of PYTHONPATH elements

Tags: python, python-import, python-2.6

I'll shorten the notation.  I have

```
PYTHONPATH=/path1/dir1:/path2/dir2
```

Structures:

```
/path1/dir1/
    README
    muggle.py
    ...
    utils/

/path2/dir2/
    __init__.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        pkg2/
            __init__.py
            mod2.py
```

`dir1` has a module `utils`, but is not, itself a package: no `__init__.py`
`dir2` has a module `utils`, and *does* have `__init__.py`

My boiler-plate code (before `dir1` was part of the environment) has imports from `dir2` of the form

```
from utils.pkg2.mod2 import func2
```

The problem comes in that I'm now adapting this code to call functions that import from `utils` in `dir1`; I cannot alter that part of the environment.

What can I do to make my code go for the `dir2/utils` module?  Unfortunately, this also needs to be adaptable to Python 2.6.6 and later.

I have search existing questions on SO and elsewhere; all the answers I've found depend on some package "handle" that I do not have.

Comment: `dir2` is a package, so it should have been `from dir2.utils.pkg2.mod2 import func2` in the first place, no?  Was the code relying on implicit relative imports?  Why do you have a directory from *inside* the package (`/path2/dir2`) listed in your PYTHONPATH at all?

Comment: `foo/__init__.py` -> is package not a module `foo.py` is a module. `foo/bar.py` is a module `bar` inside package `foo`

Comment: You could modify "sys.path" before  the relevant imports (and set back afterwards) so that it only contains the desired path.

Comment: you have `from utils.pkg2.mod2 import func2` in your code base, then you added dir1 and everything blows up,I'm right?

Comment: @geckos That's right.  `wim` solved the problem in good stead.  Thanks to everyone for the comments; they're good ammo for cleaning up the top level of our integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This import statement is incorrect:

```
from utils.pkg2.mod2 import func2
```

If it has ever worked correctly, that was relying on resolving with the current working directory, implicit relative imports in Python 2.x, or a manually munged `PYTHONPATH` / `sys.path`.

This is the type of import for which PEP8 said:

> Implicit relative imports should *never* be used and have been removed in Python 3.

So what to do instead? `sys.path` should be augmented with top-level directories, not intra-package directories, i.e.:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path1/dir1:/path2
```

And change imports like this:

```
from dir2.utils.pkg2.mod2 import func2
```

Now the *sub-package* `dir2.utils` is [namespaced](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py#L21) from the top-level package `utils`.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks; that 2=>3 change came before I was part of our system design here, and I'd forgotten the semantic change.